# Multiple List<Widget> in TabBarView with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, widget

I am a flutter beginner.
I want to add multiple arrays of widgets in TabBarView.
I have 3 Arrays with ListView containing Card Widgets in them.

Is it possible to put multiple Arrays in TabBarView?
How can I achieve that?

Here is my code.

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final List<Widget> stack = <Widget>[];
        final List<Widget> info  = <Widget>[
          _infoScreen();
        ];
        final List<Widget> addStuff   = <Widget>[
          _someAdditionalStuff()
        ];
        if (_queryProductError == null) {
          stack.add(
            ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildConnectionCheckTile(),
                _buildProductList(),
                _adsTitle(),
                _adsButton(),
                _buildRestoreButton(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          stack.add(Center(
            child: Text(_queryProductError!),
          ));
        }
        if (_purchasePending) {
          stack.add(
            // TODO(goderbauer): Make this const when that's available on stable.
            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
            Stack(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.3,
                  child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket_outlined),
                text : 'Донације'),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                text : 'Инфо'),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Донације'),
          leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: (){ main();},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_sharp),
            )
        ),
        body: new TabBarView(
          children:
            stack,
            info,
            addStuff,
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This does not work and gives me a "Too much positional arguments exceptions in TabBarView".

The example below is with 3 Card Widgets and works fine but is not what I want:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket_outlined),
                text : 'Донације'),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                text : 'Инфо'),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Донације'),
          leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: (){ main();},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_sharp),
            )
        ),
        body: new TabBarView(
          children:
            _buildProductList
            _infoScreen
            _someAdditionalStuff

        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I would like to have 5 Widgets on Tab 1
and 2 Widgets on Tab 2 and 1 Widget on Tab 3

I tried a few things but I don't get it.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your children property in the TabBarView widget needs to be an array of widgets. Where array is equal to the length defined for the number of tabs.

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket_outlined),
              text : 'Донације'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
              text : 'Инфо'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Донације'),
        leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: (){ main();},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_sharp),
          )
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [ //TabBarView wants an array of children where length === children.length
          stack,
          info,
          // need to add one more widget here because the length of the DefaultTabController is set to 3
        ]
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out that per Tab, only one Widget is possible, so I managed it with ListTile and Column inside instead of Cards, so I have only One ListView Widget instead of a couple of Card Widgets. It doesn't look like I want it to do with the Card Widgets but I am good with this solution, because I didn't found another.